# Scala adding to an Int to a single member

Tags: scala, int, addition

So if I have the following object:

```
case class Purple(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)
```

and I want to make a method that adds 25 to only one of the members.

I would imagine the following (if I want to add it to x):

```
def add25ToX(purple: Purple) : Purple = {
this.x + 25 }
```

But I can't because it wants Purple back and not an Int. How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic principle of immutable structures: you don't modify the existing data. Instead, you return a new `Purple` with a modified value. You can use the copy constructor for conciseness:

```
def add25ToX(purple: Purple): Purple = purple.copy(x = purple.x + 25)
```

Alternatively you can define it inside the class

```
case class Purple(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) {
  def add25ToX: Purple = this.copy(x = x + 25)
}
```